# chromedriver verbose log inside selenium docker

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver

Locally, for detailed log, I would run

```
chromedriver --verbose --log-path=/
```

Cam I get same detailed log inside docker-container?
I'm using https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium standalone-chrome:3.141.59-zirconium . Starting with

```
version: "3"
services:

  selenium:
    image: docker.artifactory1.lancope.ciscolabs.com/selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-zirconium
    ports:
      - '4444:4444'
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - ./end-to-end-test/data/downloads:/home/seluser/Downloads
    environment:
      - GRID_DEBUG=true
```

Comment: I opened terminal session to container use command ```docker exec -it name /bin/sh``` and run `chromedriver --verbose` and see logs

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `SE_OPTS` environment variable to pass in whatever flags you need. For example, you can do the following:

```bash
docker run --rm -it --env SE_OPTS="--log-level FINE" -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

See the [SE_OPTS Selenium Configuration Options](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#se_opts-selenium-configuration-options) and [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#troubleshooting) sections of the docker-selenium repository.